How to modify a Windows ISO image on Linux?
I am using Ubuntu. I have a Windows 10 consumer ISO image and I want to modify the ISO to remove all editions from it but keep the Pro edition and that will be in index 4, and need to do all that work just using CLI.
How to do that?

Unpack the ISO using 7z or bsdtar or by mounting it and copying files out, then use wimdelete from wimlib-imagex to remove unnecessary parts of the Sources/Install.wim file.
Then, if you are planning to write it to a USB stick – don't bother creating a new ISO image (as the original wasn't meant for USB sticks anyway; the .iso file was a CD/DVD image).
Instead just copy the files to a FAT32 formatted partition if you want the USB stick to be UEFI-bootable. (An image for writing to USB in future can be prepared by creating a large file using fallocate, attaching it with losetup -P and partitioning it using fdisk like a real disk.)
(For the rare occasion when it needs to be "legacy mode" bootable, you'd need to use NTFS instead, and use ms-sys to install a standard MBR and a Win7+ NTFS boot sector.)

I need to create it as iso after that.

Will you be writing the iso to a CD or using it with virtual CD-ROM?

Neither. Just want it as iso file.

The contents of the ISO file are going to depend on what you're using it for... I mean, if you just want an ISO that doesn't boot on any system, then just build one with plain mkisofs. It'll be a legitimate ISO9660 image, you can double-click mount it on Windows, etc. It won't boot though.

Of course i need it bootable & able to burn it on a usb or a cd or run it on a virtual machine.
